# Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_\mathbb{R}\vert f(x+n)-f(x)\vert dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_\mathbb{R}\vert f(x+n)-f(x)\vert dx$.

I think the limit is $2\Vert f\Vert_{L^1}$, as this result holds for simple functions. If we first consider $f$ is a simple function, after some large $n$, support of $f(x+n)$ and $f(x)$ are going to be disjoint which will give the result I guess.

But I could not generalize my idea by density, because I could  get only one side inequality by density,

Maybe my guess is wrong, Thanks in advance for any help/hint suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You see how to do this when $f$ is compactly supported. Now approximate arbitrary $f$ by $f\chi_{[-N,N]}$, where $N$ is large enough to make the integral of $|f-f\chi_{[-N,N]}|$ less than $\epsilon$.

Solution: Note

$$\left| \int |f_N(x+n) -f_N(x)| - \int |f(x+n)-f(x)| \right| \le  \int ||f_N(x+n) -f_N(x)| - |f(x+n)-f(x)||.$$

Now apply the reverse triangle inequality $||a|-|b||<|a-b|$.

$$\le \int |f_N(x+n) -f_N(x) -f(x+n)+f(x)| \le \int |f_N(x+n) - f(x+n)| + \int |f(x)-f_N(x)|.$$

We chose $N$ so that both terms on the right hand side are less than $\epsilon$. So the problem reduces to the compactly supported case, which you know how to do.

Comment: Let $f_N=f\chi_{(-N,N)}$, for sufficiently large $N$: $\int |f(x+n)-f(x)|\leq\int\vert f(x+n)-f_N(x+n)+f_N(x+n)-f_N(x)+f_N(x)-f(x)\vert\leq \epsilon+\int |f_N(x+n)-f_N(x)|+\epsilon$, when we take the integral, middle terms goes $\Vert f_N\Vert_{L^1}$. Still we get inequality ($\leq$)not equality, and also how can I take the limit into integral? integrant is dominated by $L^1$ function $2|f|$ yet I don't know where does integrand converge pointwise. I am not comfortable with using density for this one

Comment: @seriouslydivergent See edit.

Comment: Got it thank you very much!